Why is only the title displayed and not the content when using next-mdx-remote with Next.js?
I am using next-mdx-remote with Next.js to render MDX content on a page, but only the title from the frontmatter is being displayed, and the actual MDX content is not showing up. Here is my setup:
PostPage.tsx
import { MDXRemote, MDXRemoteSerializeResult } from 'next-mdx-remote/rsc';
import { getPostBySlug } from '../../../lib/mdx';

export interface Props {
  source: MDXRemoteSerializeResult;
  frontmatter: {
    title: string;
    date: string;
  };
}

export default async function PostPage() {
  const { source, frontmatter } = await getPostBySlug();
  console.log('MDX Source:', source);
  console.log('Frontmatter:', frontmatter);

  return (
    <div className="pt-16">
      <h1>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
      <MDXRemote source={source} />
    </div>
  );
}

lib/mdx.js
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import matter from 'gray-matter';
import path from 'path';

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'content/biography');

export async function getPostBySlug() {
  const filePath = path.join(postsDirectory, `life.mdx`);
  const mdxText = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');

  // Parse the front matter and content
  const { content, data } = matter(mdxText);

  // Serialize the content
  const mdxSource = await serialize(content, { scope: data });
  console.log('Serialized MDX Source:', mdxSource);

  return {
    source: mdxSource,
    frontmatter: data,
  };
}

export async function getAllPostSlugs() {
  const filenames = await fs.readdir(postsDirectory);
  return filenames.map((filename) => filename.replace('.mdx', ''));
}

life.mdx in content/biography
---
title: "Example Post"
date: "2023-01-01"
---

# Hello, world!

This is an example post written in MDX.

next.config.mjs
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';
import createMDX from '@next/mdx';

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // Configure `pageExtensions`` to include MDX files
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  // Optionally, add any other Next.js config below
};

const withMDX = createMDX({
  // Add markdown plugins here, as desired
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
});

// Wrap MDX and Next.js config with each other
export default withMDX(nextConfig);

When I navigate to the PostPage using the /about route, only the title "Example Post" is displayed, but the content (e.g., "# Hello, world!") is not rendered.
How can I resolve this issue to display the MDX content correctly?

This was due to the handling of React Server Components (RSC). Here's how I did to resolve this issue:
Steps to Resolve
Update getPostBySlug to Return Raw MDX Content:
Instead of serializing the MDX content using next-mdx-remote/serialize, return the raw MDX content directly. This aligns with the handling required for React Server Components.
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'content/biography');

export async function getPostBySlug(slug: string) {
    const postFilePath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${slug}.mdx`);
    const fileContent = await fs.readFile(postFilePath, 'utf8');
    return fileContent;
}

Compile MDX Content with Frontmatter Parsing:
Use the compileMDX function to compile the MDX content and parse the frontmatter.
import { compileMDX } from 'next-mdx-remote/rsc';
import { useMDXComponents } from 'next-mdx-remote';

export default async function PostPage({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
    const source = await getPostBySlug(params.slug);
    const components = useMDXComponents({});
    const { content, frontmatter } = await compileMDX<{ title: string, date: string }>({
        source: source,
        components: components,
        options: {
            parseFrontmatter: true,
        },
    });

    return (
        <div className="pt-16">
            <h1>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
            <div className="prose-strong:text-gray-900 dark:prose-em:text-slate-400 dark:prose-strong:text-slate-400 prose-em:text-gray-900">
                {content}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

Ensure Correct Configuration:
Make sure your next.config.mjs is set up to support MDX files and plugins correctly.
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';
import createMDX from '@next/mdx';

const nextConfig = {
    pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
};

const withMDX = createMDX({
    options: {
        remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
        rehypePlugins: [],
    },
});

export default withMDX(nextConfig);

Summary
Modify getPostBySlug to return raw MDX content. Use compileMDX to handle the compilation and frontmatter parsing.
By following these steps, I was able to render both the title from the frontmatter and the actual MDX content properly.
References
next-mdx-remote Documentation - React Server Components (RSC)
